# Javascript-list of nested tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to create the following type of HTML structure:

```
<div id="dcontent">
    <ul class="thm">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/theme1.jpg" id="t1" border="none"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/theme2.jpg" id="t2" border="none"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/theme3.jpg" id="t3" border="none"/></a></li>
```

I need to create 18 nested images this way so I use the following Javascript loop:

```
for (var count = 1; count < 19; count++) {
    newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.setAttribute('id', 'l' + count);
    newLink = document.createElement('a');
    newLink.setAttribute('href', '#');
    newLink.setAttribute('id', 'a' + count);
    $(newLink).appendTo('#l' + count);
    newImg = document.createElement('img');
    newImg.setAttribute('src', thumbPath + count + '.jpg');
    newImg.setAttribute('id', 't' + count);
    newImg.setAttribute('border', 'none');
    $(newImg).appendTo('#a' + count);
    $(newLi).appendTo('.thm');
}
```

The code outputs only `li` nested in `ul` which is nested in `div`. Is it better to use jQuery because I read that `document.createElement` (pure Javascript) is faster method. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"Is it better to use jQuery..."* is subjective and solicits opinion instead of fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var $thm = $('.thm');
 for(var count=1; count<19; count++)
 {
    var $li = $('<li><a href="#"><img src="img/theme' + count + '.jpg" id="t' + count + '" border="none"/></a></li>')
    $thm.append($li);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any jQuery at all.

You can replace the `appendTo` functions as well, with

```
var parent = document.getElementById("id");
parent.appendChild(child);
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a set of abstractions to ease your work with JavaScript. This does mean you will perform extra logic to perform the same task.

You need to find a balance between performance at runtime and the time it takes for you to develop.